# A creature gaining Energie through Movement

Tags: science-fiction, xenobiology, aliens, energy

I basically have a Facultative anaerobic organism that lives in space (not from another planet but the vacuum of space) and the creature needs to travel to survive. It's not just movement that keeps it alive, it needs to be in different places too. Could there be anything that grounds this to science, that it needs to travel to live?

Comment: If you read the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tag wikis, you'll discover they're mutually exclusive. I deleted the one I felt was least relevant. I like the quesiton, but we'll need to stretch things a bit to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

We have something similar with some shark species. They must constantly swim or die (obligate ram ventilation). They need to keep water flowing through their gills and have no other mechanism for doing so except moving.

So your creature needs something in space to live, perhaps not much but it's essential to life and they need to keep moving. They deplete it for a time wherever they have been, so they have to keep moving to new places.

Comment: +1 I want to add that "empty space" actually isn't that empty. There are "a lot" of dust particles flowing around that this species could feed of.

Answer (score 2):

The first idea that comes to mind is that your creature is a living [electrodynamic tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether).

> Electrodynamic tethers (EDTs) are long conducting wires, such as one deployed from a tether satellite, which can operate on electromagnetic principles as generators, by converting their kinetic energy to electrical energy, or as motors, converting electrical energy to kinetic energy.

The entity has numerous long conductive filaments that interact with ambient magnetic fields around planets and stars. It has the ability to garner energy by moving through magnetic fields, or spend energy to propel off of them. And probably some form of capacitor bank to store and discharge the energy it collects.

Comment: Note that this would be converting its motion to electricity, braking itself in the process. It would be generating electricity as it braked itself down into a gas giant's gravity well to grab some tasty ices from its rings. It would then need to produce electricity to climb back out, so it will ultimately need some other source of energy. And the energy needed to run an electrodynamic tether is much more than can be realistically stored (and capacitors don't store much anyway).